# WPF "Booking chart"

Tags: wpf

Greetings, 
Currently I am in process of developing an application for booking (etc. rooms). The most painful thing in front of me: "The booking chart". It should looks similarly to the following thing:
http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4807/99573694.gif

Any suggestion how can I build the "skeleton" of the booking chart? should i use grid etc? I would like to navigate through the days and additionally passed number of items and current datetime range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example it looks like a job for DataGrid (http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117 if you're on WPF 3.5, it's part of WPF 4).

I would implement the navigation functionality by using LINQ to filter your data set to the range you're interested in. The navigation controls would have to be provided by you separate from the DataGrid.

Hope that helps...

Comment: ok, thank you. I will look at this asap. Does it support cell merging? and context menu?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about cell merging... Might be best to ask a separate question about this. It supports context menus though.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd need cell merging for the example you gave though.

Comment: I think i will need some cell merging if i want to have a "booking" for 3 days (as in the example). this will mean that the booking continues for 3 days

Comment: Is your "booking" just going to be a block of colour, as in your example? If so, you wouldn't need cell merging; you'd just set each cell's colour. If you wanted text to overlay the colour then that's a different matter.

Comment: well..i would like to have some texts on that cells, and what i I will have a booking from 12.12.2009 to 15-12-2009. How should Idisplay it? The better thing will be to merge 3 cells

Comment: the other thing is that for eaech booking (lets say 3 days booking i would like to have a context menu with some option - operations to do on that booking

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to the Scheduling tool Billy Hollis shows in dnr tv number 115 which is a listbox on its side.

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115
Mike